# Desktop Sharing in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: remote-desktop

Recently i had Installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my Desktop Machine my system is 15 with 8 GB RAM.

After Installed Ubuntu it's working properly but we are having one issue Regarding Desktop sharing. we install desktop sharing from software center but not access machine from other system. please suggest me what should i do.

Answer (score 1):

Vino, the remote desktop sharing software, does not run on Wayland, the default display manager for 17.10.

I was in the same corner, you can fix it by not using Wayland:

Going back to the login screen and choosing 'Gnome on Xorg' from the settings (the gear symbol) menu before logging in allows Vino to work again.

If you want to have this parmanently, without having to switch each time you log-in, you can do this via modifying the `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`with your favourite editor

`sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

and edit it to have Wayland disabled

```
[daemon]
# Uncoment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
WaylandEnable=false
```

and your next reboot will not have Wayland as an option, only gnome(*)

(*)*Unless you installed Unity, of course.*